# Testing database on Windows Phone 7 mango

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-7.1

I need to write unit tests for my WP7 app. Tests are run on desktop(not on device or emulator). The problem is when i try creating DataContext class on desktop framework it fails in ctor.

I use WindowsPhone's mscorlib(2.0.5.0) in references.

Looks like it needs some DLL's from phone, but im not sure what.

Possibly someone had same problem.

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Silverlight Unit Testing Framework? In that case, I'm afraid there's no way to access SQL Server CE from a SL application. See [Can a silverlight client access a local sql compact database that is stored in isolated storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331857/can-a-silverlight-client-access-a-local-sql-compact-database-that-is-stored-in-is)

I think your best go is to [mock the data context](http://andrewtokeley.net/archive/2008/07/06/mocking-linq-to-sql-datacontext.aspx).